# Understanding jQuery library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a bit confused i have been doing jQuery on code academy, i finished but, but there is something that i am not sure about it.

So do you have to download the jQuery library or something i am really confused about this, i have seen other people just linking in their html page the jQuery,
for instance they would link their html page to their JS page like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Js/Main.js"></script>
```

and then underneath it they would link another one but to an external site related to jQuery, that is the part that i am confused about. is it a thing ? im not sure, also if it might be of use i am using Sublime Text 2.

Comment: Linking to a javascript file on an external server, or your own server, doesn't really make much of a difference, as long as the URL is correct, both methods load the script.

Comment: You have to explicitly import jQuery, either from your own server of from one of several CDNs.

Comment: does that mean that you use one of those ? because ive seen someone use both, il try and find the code and show u.

Comment: @Gabriel Yes, you can do. `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need jQuery library to be loaded before any of your scripts that require jQuery to be executed. So add jQuery using a CDN like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Js/Main.js"></script>
```

Comment: ohhh, let me see if i got it right, first we have to load the library from the internet to our code, if we do it otherwise our code won't know that it's jQuery ?

Comment: thanks all of you for clearing this for me i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to link to jQuery (either a copy that you host on your site or a copy on a CDN, such as Google's hosted copy). Then, you need to link to or include your own code that uses jQuery. The order matters; your code will break if it uses jQuery but you load it first.

For example,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/your/script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery you can do, as far as I'm concerned, two things:

1. Download the jQuery code yourself and include it in your page using: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery.js"></script>`
   Or
2. Use a GoogleApis link to have the browser download it for you by using: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Both work just fine, but opinions on which to use vary from dev to dev

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have good reasons, you should use a content delivery network (CDN) instead of hosting jQuery yourself.

[3 reasons why you should let Google host jQuery for you](https://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/)